# passing javascript parameter to asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a Javascript function and i want to pass a parameter from javascript to asp.net. my sample code like below:

```
function ConfirmMessage(message) {
            var msg = "<%= Efe.UI.WebApplication.AppCode.HelperClass.GetScreenMessage(message); %>"

alert.confirm(msg);

}
```

But I am getting error at "**message**" parameter. The error is:

> The "name" does not exist in the current context.

How can I pass parameter from javascript to asp.net?

Comment: In some scenarios it's better to take a step back from the problem and adjust the overall approach, I suspect this might be one of those scenarios. What are you ultimately trying to do? You're mixing server-side code and C# too much here. It doesn't feel right.

Comment: You might read up on [Ajax with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398874(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass parameter from javascript to server side at inline code. 
You should use jquery ajax for that.

```
var message = "value";
$.get(
url: "/yoururl/GetScreenMessage",
data: {message : message},
success: function(data){
    alert(data);    
});
```

Comment: not jQuery per se, but you'll need a different approach indeed

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it didnt worked. I thing, i have to try another way. Damn asp.net dont allow to pass parameter javascript to asp.net.

Comment: Evet @MahmutEFE, because server side rendered before javascript. If you setup relevant url, this should work.

Comment: thanks, i searched your approach on internet and finally i solved my problem. with WebMethod..

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to dynamically call a server side function with a parameter, but the `<%= %>` part is actually a Response.Write. So, during the page load the page will try to render with the `Efe.UI.WebApplication.*xxx*` method's output. 
That won't work.

You'll need a different solution all together. Most likely you'll want to use a "REST-like" service call to get the result of the "message" parameter. I would suggest you take a look at AJAX : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398874%28v=vs.100%29.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29400/Ajax-Quick-Start-FAQ